# raspberry pi captive portal

Tags: raspberry-pi, captivenetwork

I am experimenting on a 1st gen Pi with some friends. We are building a simple website for a competition and were wondering if we could use the Pi as a captive portal in order to display our site immediately after a user connects. 
http://sirlagz.net/2013/08/23/how-to-captive-portal-on-the-raspberry-pi/
I found this guide but it requires a wifi dongle for the RaspberryPi to act as an access point. My question is can I connect a router to the Pi and use that combo for our captive portal?
P.S. The site will be deployed on a local computer

Comment: One of my friend did it, so it is possible...

Comment: @AntonAtanasov Does my answer help ? If it does, please accept it.

Comment: I'm interesting for the answer too. Severals problems arise, especially when raspi is connected to router and router is also a gateway for a raspi. My plan is to use coovachilli. Maybe we can start discussion on some discussion portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. 
You'll have to configure which interface to use as a Hotspot, in your hotspot config.
HotSpot config depends on the tool you use to provide HotSpot... I use **hostapd** on my Linux Mint machine.

(I find personnally the wifi dongle simplier/quicker to use).

Note : *important to distinguish HotSpot notion from Captive notion.
Generally, one made a captive wifi hotspot.
But you can do non-captive Wifi, or captive Ethernet...
I personnally did the same (local website on server providing wifi captive hotspot. Wifi hostpot on linux (mint, based on ubuntu) and I made it captive with redirections). But I use the wifi card embedded. I have a rasp and I find wifidongle quite cool.*

Comment: Please let me know, once you get it (you will), if you get a popup on Mac, iOS and/or Android. That's the point I m working currently. I want my users/clients to get immediatly a "welcome" popup page once connected to the hotspot.

Comment: @3pic- The pop up is possible, just configure your router to redirect to another address for any url the user hits. The devices always hit a specific set of urls to check whether they have internet connectivity. If they get a 302 redirect response, the device itself throws a notification, for it has sensed a captive portal. This way you can notify a user with a notification, which will drive him to the "welcome" page.

Comment: @ParitoshWalvekar thanks. For some times I have been working it. I have understood it. I'm now working on redirection, trying to make it work with iptables, without success till now... I'm opening a question about it. Note : I dont have a physical router, I use wlan0 by creating a wifi access point on my linux machine. So I guessed iptables is the way for routing. Am I right at this point ?

Comment: Maybe this helps. Let me know https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd

Comment: Thanks. I have opened a question about it: http://superuser.com/questions/936764/redirect-routing-for-my-access-point-is-iptables-right-for

Comment: How do you solve situation, when raspi is connected to router and should act as captive portal for that router clients, but the router is also a gateway for a raspi.